# Assigning the same value to multiple SAS variables

Tags: variables, sas

I have 100 different variables `ndc1-ndc100`. I need to assign the same value to all of them, something like this:

```
data prj.rx_comm_crosstab;
    length
    ndc1-ndc100   $20       
    ;                                                                    
    retain ndc1-ndc100; 
    retain cnter 0; 
    set rx_cost_by_drug;
    by yrmo subs_id mbrtype;   
    if first.mbrtype then do;                                                                                              
        ndc1-ndc100 =' ';
        cnter=0;
    end;
    ....some other code
run;
```

The line `ndc1-ndc100 = ' '` doesn't work. Is there a way to do it? I wanna avoid having to set each of the 100 variables to the same value individually.

Comment: Is the same value, a value such as missing or something else entirely? For missing, you can do CALL MISSING()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use an array as shown below.

```
data class;
length
ndc1-ndc10   $20 ;
set sashelp.class;
 array nd(*) $ ndc1-ndc10 ;
 if age = 13 then do;
 do i=1 to dim(nd);
     nd{i}="Hello";
  end;
  end;
run;
```